# Google search appliance GSA URL regarding to suggestion

Tags: google-search-appliance

I'm facing some problem regarding to query hit for generating suggestion.
Please take a look below URL structure and suggest the appropriate URL modification.

> http://{host-name}/search?start=0&num=1000&site=bhtest&output=xml&client=pp_frontend&filter=0&getfields=*&q=sken+inmeta:contenttype~Product%20OR%20inmeta:contenttype~Content

In the above query, search term is "sken", GSA suggestion tag should appear and provide suggestion for "skin" but it is not happening

When I change the query to:

> http://{host-name}/search?start=0&num=1000&site=bhtest&output=xml&client=pp_frontend&filter=0&getfields=*&q=sken

Then it provides the suggestions.

Can you please help to find out the problem in first one URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suggestions are not returned when you add metadata filters.  See the search protocol reference found [here](http://static.googleusercontent.com/media/www.google.com/en/us/support/enterprise/static/gsa/docs/admin/70/gsa_doc_set/xml_reference/xml_reference.pdf)

The way to work around this is to issue two queries, one with your filter and one without.

Answer (score 0):

It is related to language parameter in my oppinion. Try use [&lr](http://www.google.com/support/enterprise/static/gsa/docs/admin/72/gsa_doc_set/xml_reference/request_format.html#1077312) and [&hl](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-search-appliance-help/06wZss8NPjI) parameters. GSA suggest by this parameters.